# iterating through array of class elements and selecting sibling in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a structure in html like

```
 <div class="combo-wrapper" tabindex="0" style="display: inline-block; width: 120px; height: 23px;">
<div class="combo-button" style="width: 20px; height: 23px; display: inline-block;"></div>
<div class="combo-selected" style="width: 100px; height: 23px; display: inline-block;">Pending For Upload L2-GM</div>
</div>
```

In its sibling i have a dropdown

```
<select class="bydd">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="H">Hold</option>
<option value="D">Delete</option>
</select>
```

When i tried to set title

```
$(".combo-wrapper").each(function (i) {

        $('.combo-wrapper')[i].attr("title", $('.combo-wrapper')[i].siblings(".bydd option:selected").text());

    });
```

it throws undefined error

`$('.combo-wrapper')[0].siblings()`  itself throws not a function error in console

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: $('.combo-wrapper')[0] is DOM Element, not jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

When you retrieve a value from a jQuery object by index you're actually getting the underlying DOMElement not a jQuery object, hence the `undefined function` error when attempting to get the `attr`.

To get a jQuery object by index you need to use the `eq()` method:

```
$('.combo-wrapper').eq(i).attr("title", $('.combo-wrapper').eq(i).siblings(".bydd option:selected").text());
```

Or you can use the `:eq` selector:

```
$('.combo-wrapper:eq(' + i + ')').attr("title", $('.combo-wrapper:eq(' + i + ')').siblings(".bydd option:selected").text());
```

Answer (score 1):

because `$('.combo-wrapper')[0]` returns a dom element reference which does not have jQuery related methods.

You can use `this`(it is again a dom element reference not a jQuery wrapper) to refer to the current element in the each loop, and then wrap it in jQuery to use jQuery method on it

```
$(".combo-wrapper").each(function (i) {

    $(this).attr("title", $(this).siblings(".bydd").find("option:selected").text());

});
```

---

Another way is

```
$(".combo-wrapper").attr("title", function () {
    return $(this).siblings(".bydd").find("option:selected").text()
});
```